# How to use GitHub secrets or GitHub environment variables in build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, github-actions

I have some authentication secrets in GitHub and I have to use them in spring boot build.gradle file is there any example for the same.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main possibilities IMHO:

**1. Externalize the data:**

Create a new file, let's say `secrets.gradle`, where you set your secrets, like:

```
mySecretUser = "me"
mySecretPassword = "password123"
```

Make sure, this file is never commited to your versioning system, e.g. by adding it to `.gitignore`!

Then, in your `build.gradle`, you can refer it like so:

```
apply from: 'secrets.gradle'
```

This would help you with local development e.g.

**2. Use environment variables:**

You can set the secrets as environent variables like this:

```
set mySecretUser=me
set mySecretPassword=password123
```

(On Windows, in Unix you might rather use `export` instead of `set`.)

Then, you can use them in your `build.gradle` like this:

```
mySecretUser = "$System.env.mySecretUser"
mySecretPassword = "$System.env.mySecretPassword"
```

**2½ - Combine both methods:**

In order to look for the `secrets.gradle` file and just use the environment variables, if it does not exist, you can do it like this in your `build.gradle`:

```
if (file('secrets.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: 'secrets.gradle'
}
else {
    mySecretUser = "$System.env.mySecretUser"
    mySecretPassword = "$System.env.mySecretPassword"
}
```

**Final note:**

You didn't write anything about your setup - is the Gradle build executed locally or on a build server like Jenkins? In the first case, the `secrets.gradle` approach might be the better way to go. On a Jenkins server, you'll find great possibilities to store credentials as build environment variables via the configuration.

Anyway, I just gave some suggestions here. Please make sure, your secrets are really kept secret and not inadvertantly revealed. As I don't know your setup, I cannot say anything about how safe these methods are in your case.

Comment: Note that first you need to export your secrets as env vars, using something like https://github.com/oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action

Comment: @oNaiPs, that only applies to GitHub actions pipelines. It is not generally needed/applicable. You can export your secrets as env variables via shell/cmd as I suggested or in many other ways.

Comment: you're right. When I read Github Secrets, assumed we'd be using Actions but that does not have to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Extending @ahuemmer's solution, I was using external secrets in my `gradle.build` `repositories` closure nested under a `subprojects` closure. In order to make this solution work, I had to set my secrets in `secrets.gradle` as follows:

```
project.ext.mySecretUser = "me"
project.ext.mySecretPassword = "password123"
```

Then my main `gradle.build` file looked like this:

```
if (file('secrets.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: 'secrets.gradle'
}
else {
    project.ext.mySecretUser = System.getenv('mySecretUser')
    project.ext.mySecretPassword = System.getenv('mySecretPassword')
}

subprojects {


    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username mySecretUser
                password mySecretPassword
            }
            url = 'https://some-internal-repo.com/internal-repo'
            name = 'some-internal-repo'
        }
}
```